# Algorithm to Model Averages

Tags: java, php, algorithm, math, curve-fitting

I'm trying to build an algorithm that finds the ideal value from scattered points.

Basically I have data like:

```
Point 4.9 - value 200
Point 5.3 - value 940
Point 5.9 - value 640
Point 13.7 - value 300
```

And I need to build a mathematical curve (based on velocity and incline) that will approximate the highest point of this set as 5.5 with a value of 980.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The first thing of curve fitting is to determine whether you want the curve to exactly pass your data points or not. Then, we can decide what algorithm (and what kind of curve) to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best fit curve could be found with the Levenburg-Marquardt algorithm. See Numerical Recipes in C or C++ by Press et. al. e.g.

A lower quality solution could be obtained with a cubic spline, e.g. See the same book as above, or an advance engineering math book (Kreyzig e.g.).

Comment: I think claiming LMA as the "best" fit and cubic spline as "lower quality" solution is kind of mis-leading here. You would need to look at what data you have and what kind of goal you want to achieve to decide what the best algorithm to use.